Regularity of $R / (I+J)$ in terms of the regularity of $I$ and $J$
I am studying the Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity (simply said regularity) function and have the following situation:
Let $ I $ and $ J $ be two graded ideals in $ R = K[X] $, where $ X = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\} $ is a set of variables over a field $ K $.
I am interested in understanding whether it is possible to express $ \mathrm{reg}(R/(I+J)) $ in terms of $ \mathrm{reg}(I) $ and $ \mathrm{reg}(J) $.
I know that in the specific case where there is a partition of $ X $ into two disjoint subsets $ X_1 $ and $ X_2 $, with $ I \subset K[X_1] $ and $ J \subset K[X_2] $, we have the following formula:
$$
\mathrm{reg}(R/(I+J)) = \mathrm{reg}(K[X_1]/I) + \mathrm{reg}(K[X_2]/J)
$$
if the involved $ K $-algebras are Cohen-Macaulay.
My question is:

Is there a similar relationship or inequality between $ \mathrm{reg}(R/(I+J)) $, $ \mathrm{reg}(I) $, and $ \mathrm{reg}(J) $ in the general case, without the assumption that $ I $ and $ J $ are defined on separate sets of variables?

Any insights or references on this would be greatly appreciated!

Why did you add the betti-numbers tag? What is the relation?

Because $\mathrm{reg}(R/I)$ can be defined by $$\mathrm{max}{j:\beta_{i,i+j}(R/I)\neq 0, \text{for some } i},$$ where $\beta_{i,i+j}(R/I)$ is the $(i,i+j)$-th graded Betti number of $R/I$.
